# Product in nested navigation

Tags: structure, elementtype, menu

I'm currenty running Craft (v3) Commerce (v2) and have a difficult structure.

This is my menu now:

- `single` home page.
- `single` about page.
- `channel` blog page.

It has to be with the products in the menu, but I don't know what would be the best structure. The products are under 2 categories. So it has te be something like this:

- `single` home page.
- `single` about page.
- `channel` blog page.
- `?` cars (products) page

  - `?` fast cars page

    - Fast car 1
    - Fast car 2
    - Fast car 3
  - `?` slow cars

    - `?` brand

      - Slow car 1
      - Slow car 2
      - Slow car 3
    - `?` other brand

      - Slow car 4
      - Slow car 5

At the `?` I don't know what is the best type of page, or maybe it has to be a category. Also, the uri for the slow car has to be: `cars/slow-cars/brand/{slug}`.

Anyone an idea what would be the best solution?